# Django NoReverseMatch - content doesn't load properly

Tags: python, django

I have a blog app in my Django project that is based on [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/get-started-with-django-1/#share-your-knowledge-with-a-blog). With the link  to the blog placed in my main.html template, the site throws a NoReverseMatch error. I can't seem to figure it out. Here's the HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'blog_app:blog' %}" class="nav-link" id="header">Blog</a></li>
```

Here's the 'project-level' urls.py code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from main import views

from django.conf.urls import include
from django.urls import path
from main.views import dashboard, register, about, blog

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name='main'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('dashboard/', dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
    path('about/', about, name='about'),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Here's the 'main' urls.py:

```
# main/urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from main.views import dashboard, register

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', blog, name='blog'),
]
```

Here's the 'blog' urls.py code:

```
# blog/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blog_index, name='blog_index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.blog_detail, name='blog_detail'),
    path('<category>/', views.blog_category, name='blog_category'),
]
```

Here's the views.py code:

```
# main/views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.urls import reverse
from main.forms import CustomUserCreationForm

# Create your views here.

def main(request):
    return render(request, 'main.html', {})

def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html')

def admin(request):
    return render(request, 'admin')

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html')


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(
            request, 'users/register.html',
            {'form': CustomUserCreationForm}
        )
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            auth_login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('<h1>Invalid</h1>')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def blog(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_index.html')
```

Here is the 'blog' views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import Post, Comment
from .forms import CommentForm

# Create your views here.

def blog_index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_on')
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_index.html', context)
#    return render(request, 'blog_index.html', context)

def blog_category(request, category):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        categories__name__contains=category
    ).order_by(
        '-created_on'
    )
    context = {
        'category': category,
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_category.html', context)
#    return render(request, 'blog_category.html', context)

def blog_detail(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = Comment(
                author=form.cleaned_data['author'],
                body=form.cleaned_data['body'],
                post=post
            )
            comment.save()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'comments': comments,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_detail.html', context)
#    return render(request, 'blog_detail.html', context)
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://example.com/

Django Version: 4.2.1
Python Version: 3.10.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main',
 'blog']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/user/dev/example.com/main/templates/main.html, error at line 27
   Reverse for 'blog' not found. 'blog' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   17 :     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
   18 :       <div class="container-fluid">
   19 :         <a href="{% url 'main' %}"><img id="logo" class="rounded" src="{% static 'images/ls-logo.gif' %}"></a>
   20 :         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
   21 :           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   22 :         </button>
   23 :         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar"> 
   24 :           <ul class="nav">
   25 :             <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'main' %}" class="nav-link" id="header">Home</a></li>
   26 :             <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}" class="nav-link"id="header">Dashboard</a></li>
   27 :             <li class="nav-item"><a href=" {% url 'blog_app:blog' %} " class="nav-link" id="header">Blog</a></li>
   28 :             <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'about' %}" class="nav-link" id="header">About Me</a></li>
   29 :             <li class="nav-item">
   30 :               <div>
   31 :                 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   32 :                 <a class="nav-link" id="header" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
   33 :                 {% else %}
   34 :                 <a class="nav-link" id="header" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
   35 :                 {% endif %}
   36 :               </div>
   37 :             </li>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/main/views.py", line 13, in main
    return render(request, 'main.html', {})
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 471, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'blog' not found. 'blog' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must passed the **pk** in your href a tag in the **blog/blog_detail.html** template like this `href="{% url 'blog_app:blog' blog.pk %}"` you forget to pass the **PK** and also **category** in your href tags, that's why iterpreter complains that there is no **NoReverseMatch**. I forget to tell, If you want to use **category** in your URL  you must pass its type too like this :  `path('<str:category>/', views.blog_category, name='blog_category'),`

I think that I understand what exactly you want, try this : `href="{% url 'blog_app:blog' post.pk %}"`. You want to fetch one **Post** am I right?

Comment: I tried changing the `href` tag to `{% url 'blog_app:blog' blog.pk %}` but didn't see any change, it still threw the NoReverseMatch error. Changing the path to `path('<str:category>/'` didn't seem to affect anything either. Sorry for my ignorance, I'm still confused.

Comment: I've updated the link in my template to `href="{% url 'blog_app:blog_index' 'blog' blog_index.pk %}"`, and now I'm getting this NoReverseMatch error: `NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'blog_index' with arguments '('blog', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/\\Z']`

Comment: I tried setting the link to `<li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'blog_app:blog' post.pk %}" class="nav-link" id="header">Blog</a></li>`, but I still got the NoReverseMatch error.
What I want is for the "Blog" link on the homepage to navigate to the blog's index page, which is located in my project at `blog/templates/blog_index.html`, but I'd settle for a single post at this point. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.